# What program is making this sound and how can I make it stop

Tags: windows-xp, audio

Some program is intermittently making this weird "chook ... chick" sound, no more than every 5 minutes, but sometimes hours or days between making it.  There seems to be no pattern as to when it happens, but the sound is definitely coming from the speakers, and is always the same, so I'm pretty confident some piece of software I'm running is playing the sound.  Today, I managed to record it, and I've posted it here:

http://tristanhavelick.com/chook-chick.mp3

Short of closing my programs one by one, and seeing if the sound continues, are there any tricks for tracking down a problem like this?  Is there any software that can trace what sounds come from what programs (something like tcpview with waveforms)?

I am running windows xp.

Comment: Sounds like when you click on a folder or when you refresh a web page... Nice chook-chick ;)

Comment: Have you tried searching on your hard drives for *.WAV, *.MP3, *.OGG files that play that sound? You could find it, if it's not embedded inside the program.

Comment: Could it be linked to a popup blocker?

Comment: Could it be a Popup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me like the Windows Search dog.

Do you have Windows Search (press Windows-Key and F) open? It makes the same noise - I think it's the dog panting.

You could verify this by opening Windows Search and (right-)clicking on the dog. Every time I do this I get a similar noise.

As for stopping it, assuming that it is the search-dog, you could try turning off the animated character using the right-click menu on the dog.

Comment: As for stopping it, assuming that it is the search-dog, you could try turning off the animated character using the right-click menu on the dog.

Comment: You should edit your answer to add information instead of adding a comment. It makes it easier to read. *(I added your comment to your answer)*

Comment: @Nifle - aah, yep, fair point. Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: right-clicking the dog sounds mighty similar, but not exactly the same.  I think this is probably it, for some other animation, so +1 for now, will accept if I go 3 days without hearing the sound.

Answer (score 1):

This is often the default alert sound from Windows Live Messenger. Unfortunately even if you have alerts turned off, the sound option is under the different sounds menu option:

Simpy go to: Tools > Options > Sounds > Contacts Sign-in > Don't play a sound