# Scratching sound on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

My audio in Windows 7 is not working properly lately. When I am playing a song/movie sometimes in between I hear really bad scratching sound.

I wondered If my speakers were the problem, so I hooked up a pair of headphones and checked but the scratching sound was there too.

Then I switched to Linux to see if the problem remained there to, but the audio was playing just fine.

Then I came back to Windows, removed the driver and re-installed it but the problem remains.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If its windows XP it would be the [http://superuser.com/questions/112928/what-program-is-making-this-sound-and-how-can-i-make-it-stop](search dog) . Otherwise maybe keep an eye on the mixer to work out what application is doing it.

Comment: I tagged the question `windows-7` so not is not XP. And I dont understand what you mean my `keep an eye on the mixer`

Comment: The volume mixer on 7 shows the current sound output per program. This might help working out what program is doing this.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. Didn't you read the question?

Comment: Mistake on my part. Might help to have relevant information on the question itself in addition to the tag.

Comment: Details, make about your sound device? Other hardware details? Can you record that sound for us?